# Android Realm ghost record

Tags: android, realm

[model]

class File extends RealmObject {

```
@PrimaryKey
private long id;

@Index
private long pid;

....
```

}

Please not the file id "2314356523452636310L". I have not added any files with the id neither have i added any files with this as the parent id. Now when I am trying to find files with parent id as "2314356523452636310L" I am getting a couple of records. Where are these records coming from ? Surprisingly the ghost records data is not wrong they are matching with the server.

I have logged every insert into realm and I am not getting any trace of any inserts with id "2314356523452636310L" or with pid "2314356523452636310L".

A few lines more the log ....

04-29 19:33:32.012 20435-20897/...     LOOKUP CHILDS FOR PID 2314356523452636310

04-29 19:33:32.012 20435-20897/...     [NONE]

04-29 19:33:33.502 20435-20897/...     SAVING FILE FOR PID 0 : 2344182679026576787

04-29 19:33:33.502 20435-20897/...     SAVING FILE FOR PID 0 : 2343798489906982222

04-29 19:33:33.502 20435-20897/...     SAVING FILE FOR PID 0 : 2337272514733976183

.....

04-29 19:34:23.002 20435-20897/...     FOUND CHILDS FOR PID 2314356523452636310: 21

04-29 19:34:23.002 20435-20897/...     LOOKUP CHILDS FOR PID 2314356523452636310

04-29 19:34:23.002 20435-20897/...     FOUND CHILD FOR PID 2314356523452636310: 2314031677896170384

04-29 19:34:23.002 20435-20897/...     FOUND CHILD FOR PID 2314356523452636310: 2314031673601203087

04-29 19:34:23.002 20435-20897/...     FOUND CHILD FOR PID 2314356523452636310: 2314031665011268494

04-29 19:34:23.012 20435-20897/...     FOUND CHILD FOR PID 2314356523452636310: 2312171514675370485

Now as you can see the child ids were also never inserted.

The link to the entire log file:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/3bd65632-51e6-4e32-8c26-c797052283f8/33eb298db9debdb0

Comment: I have frankly no idea what this is all about, but a solid +1 for the title. You should consider writing a novel about it.

Comment: @Rick77 Thanks man but I really need to find the bug :-)

Comment: It was either inserted at some point or multi-process access caused corruption. But I think it's probably the first.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It was not getting corrupted but I was adding the data at some point from a different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was not a Realm issue. It was actually two processes accessing different sets of data and the second process was creating the data incase it was absent. Not a bug or any technical issue. It was just the complexity of the entire code base that puzzled me.